# Read a txt file in Storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have this file that is already stored in Storage. It's a txt file that contains data lines recorded as show picture below. I get this file using the Storage facade like

```
$file = Storage::get('public/' . $model->path_to_file);  
dd($file);  // <- output the picture below
```

Now I need read each line on this file, but can't figure it out how this must be done. Someone can help me?
I try this code but give me an exception:

```
$fp = fopen(Storage::path('public/' . $file_path->path_to_file), "r+");
while (($line = stream_get_line($fp, 1024 * 1024, "\n")) !== false) {
  echo $line;
}
fclose($fp);
```

> ... 580583507 05-08-2021 15:20:09 05-08-2021 15:20:47 Luca RemoteControl {260f5a65-35a4-4b57-bd21-b378f0ab7b82}): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

How this must be solve?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the comand feof (find end of file), so you can do anything you want to inside the loop.

```
$fp = fopen(Storage::path('public/' . $file_path->path_to_file), "r");
while(!feof($fp)){
    $line = fgets($fp);
    print_r($line."\n");
}
fclose($fp);
```